# SaveAsOutlookContact command is inactive

Tags: vba, ms-access

The Access 2016 student database (microsoft example template) contains an example of using the built-in "saveasoutlookcontact" command. I added this command to the ribbon to show that the command is active for the students table first  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z69B.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z69B.png). Next, I copied this table to a new database. and here's the problem - the "saveasoutlookcontact" command is now inactive. I attach a [secondscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rzna.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rzna.png). What is the reason, any help?

Comment: Review https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5fa59e84-282a-4f5b-9f95-67863d438b87/saveasoutlookcontact-problem

Comment: Yes, checked it, but still face same problem. I suppose that problem is by security ms design and a good working template enables macros permissions somewhere in an inevident way. But how?

Comment: I imported the Students table from Students db and then the button becomes active when that table is opened and a record is added. Note that SaveAsOutlookContact is already installed on the ribbon under Home>Records>More.

Comment: @June7, you did as in my question, look "that the command is active for the students table first screenshot1. " ... then you reproduced a half of question. For now is to close off ms database, create the new db with some data and to look the state of spoken saveasoutlokbutton

Comment: Why does your table have an underscore at beginning of its name? Also, your first db is not named Students so it is not the original downloaded template file. However, that shouldn't make any difference when copying table. How did you do the 'copy'?